# How can we get current date and time (IST) without system, server and Network provider in android?

Tags: android, date

We are developing an android application in which we need current date and time.

We do not get Date and Time from server because user may not have Internet connection most of time.

And We cannot use system's date and time for it. Because user can change the date and time for device.

I even checked for network provider for same. It is providing in case of SIM available. Its not working in case of Wi-Fi device only.

Is there any way to get current date and time ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Look for GPS date

Answer (score 0):

The GPS should have it. It is based on calculating tiny differences between the time multiple satellites send, so the actual time is known to it too.

Comment: Can not use GPS because Android TV not have that. Any other option do you know to achieve it. sorry for bad english

Comment: There are no other options - except magic. If you are not communicating with the outside world and you don't have GPS, then where could it come from?

Comment: can we access bios battery date time ? I am not sure just asking.